# Using hex binning for downsampling QQ plots

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, data-visualization, hexagonal-tiles

My datasets are pretty large and rendering generated *QQ plots* is slow and sometimes even freezes my browser. I know that one option that I have is simply to *downsample* the data vector. However, I wanted to try *hex binning* technique instead of downsampling. Unfortunately, I couldn't make it work (two of my several attempts are shown below). If downsampling is possible to achieve using hex binning (which I suspect is, as it's similar to histograms), I'd appreciate, if someone could show me how to do it. I use `ggplot2`. Thanks!

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=var)) + stat_qq(aes(x = var), geom = "hex")

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = var, y = ..density..)) + 
    geom_hex(aes(sample = var), stat = "qq")

print (g)
```

The *first* call results in the following error message:

```
Error: stat_qq requires the following missing aesthetics: sample
```

The *second* call results in this message:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'density' not found
```

**UPDATE:** I think that more correct variant is this, but I'm not sure what should be the arguments:

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(??, ??)) +  stat_binhex()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for exactly, but I offer a couple ways to do hexagonal binning. First with ggplot as you are trying to work with and the second with the package hexbin which seems to look better to me, but just my preference.

```
    library(ggplot2)

    x <- rgamma(1000,8,2)
    y <- rnorm(1000,4,1.5)
    binFrame <- data.frame(x,y)

    qplot(x,y,data=binFrame, geom='bin2d') # with ggplot...rectangular binning actually

    library(hexbin)
    hexbinplot(y~x, data=binFrame) # with hexbin...actually hexagonal binning
```

**Edit:**

So I was thinking a bit about this at lunch and I think the fundamental issues is that hexbining is a multidimensional data reduction technique and it seems like you are trying to do uni-variate QQ plots on really large sample, but with hexbin in ggplot. At any-rate I can think of a way to do hex bin plots with ggplot, but the best I came up with is to start from scratch and manually construct both the theoretical quantiles (x) and sample quantiles (y). So here is what I came up with.

**Basic QQ-Plot Manually**

```
# setting up manual QQ plot used to plot with and with out hexbins

    xSamp <- rgamma(1000,8,.5) # sample data
    len <- 1000
    i <- seq(1,len,by=1)
    probSeq <- (i-.5)/len # probability grid
    invCDF <- qnorm(probSeq,0,1) # theoretical quantiles for standard normal, but you could compare your sample to any distribution
    orderGam <- xSamp[order(xSamp)] # ordered sampe
    df <- data.frame(invCDF,orderGam)

    plot(invCDF,orderGam,xlab="Standard Normal Theoretical Quantiles",ylab="Standardized Data Quantiles",main="QQ-Plot")
    abline(lm(orderGam~invCDF),col="red",lwd=2)
```

[image: Regular QQ Plot]

**QQ Plot With Hexbins in ggplot:**

```
 ggplot(df, aes(invCDF, orderGam)) + stat_binhex() + geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

![QQ Plot with ggplot][2]

So at the end of the day this might not scale up readily, but if you are looking to do true multidimensional tests of normality you might think about chi-square plots for multivariate normality. cheers

Comment: Thank you for your answer - upvoting! I've seen examples of regular hex binning. My problem is that I'd like to apply it specifically to QQ plot (via ggplot2). I appreciate your help anyway!

Comment: At the end of the day this still might not be exactly what you are trying to do. If you are trying to test for multivariate normality consider putting together some multivariate chi-square plots.

Comment: I appreciate your update. This is exactly what I was trying to do, I'm accepting this answer. I certainly plan to go beyond univariate normality test. Simple univariate plots are just an initial step in visual part of my study's EDA. Thank you for your advice on multivariate chi-square plots.

Comment: I could post the following as a separate question on CrossValidated, but since we're already talking about multivariate normality, maybe you could offer your opinion. As far as I understand, testing data for multivariate normality (MVN) is usually done to detect outliers as well as confirm MVN for stat methods that imply it. In my case, structural equation modeling (SEM) generally assumes MVN, however PLS-SEM, which I plan to use, doesn't require it. So, my question is: what is the benefit of testing data for MVN in this case? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Aleksandr. I guess there doesn't seem to be one since PLS-SEM does not assume an underlying distribution. Good luck with your research.

Comment: Thank you very much! By the way, I changed your suggested code a bit (`stat_binhex(geom = "point", size = 1, bins = 300)`) and the result is really nice: http://imgur.com/Ob0mWQi.